# Avoiding misfires with Quartz

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I'm facing a painful problem with Quartz and misfires.

My App creates allows user to create CronTrigger and SimpleTrigger Jobs.

Each Job can be paused/resumed (using Scheduler.pauseJob and Scheduler.resumeJob)

The scheduler itself can be set to standby.

We'd like to discard any misfires :

- When scheduler is in standby
- When job is paused
- When the application is stopped

As explained in this blog post http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2012/04/quartz-scheduler-misfire-instructions.html, I've tried

- withMisfireHandlingInstructionDoNothing policy for CronTrigger
- withMisfireHandlingInstructionNextWithRemainingCount for SimpleTrigger

but none could discard misfires.

I'm currently using an ugly workaround in job execute method:

```
public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
    Date dateNow = new Date();
    long diff = dateNow.getTime() - context.getScheduledFireTime().getTime();
    if (diff > 500)
    {
         //its a misfire
         return;
    }

    /* rest of job execution code */
```

When scheduledFireTime is more than 500ms older than now, discard it.

But it seems that sometimes, in production, this allows some jobs to be executed (it has been reported that occurs when app is restarted)

Could that be possible ?
Is there any pretty way to avoid misfires ?

Quartz version : 2.1.7 (In a Spring 3.2.5 app)

quartz.properties

```
org.quartz.jobStore.class=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource=psqldatasource
org.quartz.dataSource.psqldatasource.driver=${db.driver}
org.quartz.dataSource.psqldatasource.URL=${db.url}
org.quartz.dataSource.psqldatasource.user=${db.usr}
org.quartz.dataSource.psqldatasource.password=${db.pwd}
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 3

org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties = false
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass =  org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.PostgreSQLDelegate
```

for Cron :

```
 JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(JobLauncher.class)
 .withIdentity(jobIdentifierBean.getNameJob(), jobIdentifierBean.getNameGroup())
 .usingJobData(...) //defining some jobData key/values
 .build();

 Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
 .withIdentity(name, group)
 .startNow()
 .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule(strCronExpression).withMisfireHandlingInstructionDoNothing())
 .build();

 try {
    scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
} catch (SchedulerException e) {
    throw e;
}
```

for SimpleTrigger (job is defined as in cron case)

```
    //avoid first fire
    GregorianCalendar g = new GregorianCalendar();
    switch (enumDelayUnits) {
        case Days:
            g.add(GregorianCalendar.HOUR, delay * 24);
            break;
        case Hours:
            g.add(GregorianCalendar.HOUR, delay);
            break;
        case Minutes:
            g.add(GregorianCalendar.MINUTE, delay);
            break;
        case Seconds:
            g.add(GregorianCalendar.SECOND, delay);
            break;
        default:
            throw new ServiceException("Unknow delay type");
    }

    Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
            .withIdentity(jobIdentifierBean.getNameTrigger(), jobIdentifierBean.getNameGroup())
            .startAt(g.getTime())
            .withSchedule(getSimpleScheduleBuilder(delay, enumDelayUnits, repeatForever))
            .build();
    try {
        scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
    } catch (SchedulerException e) {
        throw e;
    }

private SimpleScheduleBuilder getSimpleScheduleBuilder(int delay, EnumDelayUnits enumDelayType, boolean repeatForever) throws ServiceException, Exception
{
    SimpleScheduleBuilder simpleScheduleBuilder;

    simpleScheduleBuilder = SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule();
    switch (enumDelayType) {
    case Days:
        simpleScheduleBuilder.withIntervalInHours(24 * delay);
        break;
    case Hours:
        simpleScheduleBuilder.withIntervalInHours(delay);
        break;
    case Minutes:
        simpleScheduleBuilder.withIntervalInMinutes(delay);
        break;
    case Seconds:
        simpleScheduleBuilder.withIntervalInSeconds(delay);
        break;
    default:
        serviceError("Unknown delay " + enumDelayType);
    }
    if(repeatForever)
    {
        simpleScheduleBuilder.repeatForever();
    }

    simpleScheduleBuilder = simpleScheduleBuilder.withMisfireHandlingInstructionNextWithRemainingCount();

    return simpleScheduleBuilder;
}
```

Comment: Can we see your quartz configuration? The "none could discard misfires" is suspicious, if it were true probably it would be a huge bug reported by many a long time ago.

Comment: edited with quartz properties

Comment: The recently added config is mainly the jobstore configuration. The relevant part is where you are defining your schedulers, jobs, triggers, etc.

Comment: edited with definitions..

Comment: Hi, ObscurMoirage have you found a solution to this issue? I'm facing the same problem and I have misfires when my web app restart

Answer (score 9):

I am not sure if you ever figured this out, but I had a similar issue and the solution for me was related to the "misfireThreshold" in my configuration:

```
quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold
```

Mine was set to 60000 (aka 1 minute) and so upon restarting my scheduling service, if they were within a minute of being "late", they still executed.

Comment: org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold (in milliseconds), defaulting to 60000 (a minute). It defines how late the trigger should be to be considered misfired.. This property just defines the misfire condition

Comment: This answer is correct. What is not explained in the quartz docs is that when a scheduler starts, if there are jobs scheduled in the past, that have not passed the missfireThreshold, they will be run instantly, one after another, without dellay between repeated executions.

Comment: This setting helps when you want to schedule a large number of jobs (hundreds of thousands) but you don't know the exact time when they should be executed; using SimpleTriggers with misfireThreshold set to a large time delay (like week or month) will ensure that jobs will be executed whenever executor runs.

Answer (score 0):

I have dealt with the same problem - jobs ran just after resuming them from being paused.

Your workaround is useless for my situation, because it kills also jobs misfired because of full pool of executors (in that case, I really want these jobs to be executed as soon as some executor is available).

I found a better solution that works for me, although also not so elegant - unschedule the job schedule it again.

```java
void resumePausedJobAndDiscardMisfires(final JobDetail job, final Trigger trigger) {
    scheduler.unscheduleJob(trigger.getKey());
    scheduler.scheduleJob(job, Set.of(trigger), true);
    scheduler.rescheduleJob(trigger.getKey(), trigger);
}
```

Unscheduling the job really discards all it's misfires. I wish there could be some more straightforward solution, especially using the `rescheduleJob` method, one should be able to specify, if misfires should be dropped (which is the most wanted behaviour in the most cases IMHO).

Finally, also job deletion discards all misfires: `scheduler.deleteJob(jobKey);`.